# Trying to only extract a piece of innertext

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Sub VBAWebscraping2()


    Dim IEObject As Object
    
    Set IEObject = New InternetExplorer
    
    IEObject.Visible = True
    
    IEObject.navigate url:="https://streeteasy.com/building/" & Cells(2, 4).Value
        
    Do While IEObject.Busy = True Or IEObject.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        
    Loop
    
    Dim IEDocument As HTMLDocument
    Set IEDocument = IEObject.document
    
    'GRAB by classname'
    
    Dim IEElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim IEElement As IHTMLElement
    
    Set IEElements = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName("details")
    
    For Each IEElement In IEElements
    If IEElement.innerText = "price" Then
        Debug.Print (IEElement.innerText)
    End If
    Exit For
    Next
    
    
        
    'Dim lastRow As Long
    'lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    
End Sub
```

It goes to the desired location, but when it's trying to extract the price it either doesn't print in the debug menu or grabs too much. Trying to figure out a more precise way to only grab the price, a lot of the tutorials mention id tags but there aren't many on the website.

This is the website I'm trying to scrape https://streeteasy.com/building/the-cambridge-500-east-85-street-new_york/15l?card=1

Also trying to retrieve number of rooms, baths, and neighborhood

Answer (score 0):

Price you can use class

```
IEDocument.querySelector(".price").innerText
```

Same for rooms

```
IEDocument.querySelector(".first_detail_cell").innerText
```

Beds

```
IEDocument.querySelector("[class='detail_cell ']").innerText
```

Baths

```
IEDocument.querySelector("last_detail_cell").innerText
```

Looking at how the classes are named, your mileage with different pages will almost certainly vary if any of these items are missing or in a different order. You will then need to loop the element list returned by selecting for class `.detail_cell` and test the `.innerText` for the presence of the text "room", "bed" or "bath", and assign accordingly.